# Database Design Help (Activity Types and Point Weightings)

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Working currently on a project that lets team-leaders create 'competitions' - invite their employees who participate in the competition. This part of the project has been completed. I am currently struggling with one aspect of the 'create-competition' part.

To summarise:
*Within each competition, users can register results for 3 activity types (Type A, Type B and Type C.
*Each type has a different weighting - i.e. Type A is the most valued activity, and thus registers more points for the user.

My question is, how should I work with these types and the weightings in the database. Admins will be able to choose their own types and weightings for the competitions - when they build them.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you have already the competitions, users and project leaders tables, which can be something like this:

```
create table users
(user_id int,
constraint pk_users primary key (user_id)
...
);

create table project_leaders
( leader_id int,
constraint pk_leader primary key (leader_id),
user_id int,
constraint fk_leaders foreign key (user_id)
...
);

create table competitions
(competition_id int,
constraint pk_competitions primary key (competition_id),
competition_name varchar(128),
creator_id int,
constraint fk_competition_creator foreign key (creator_id) references project_leaders(leader_id),
created_at datetime,
...
);
```

Now you need a tables for Types and Weights ...

```
create table types
(type_id in,
constraint pk_types primary key (type_id),
type_name varchar (128),
...
);

create table weights
(weight_id in,
constraint pk_weight primary key (weight_id),
weight_value int,
...
);


create table types_weights
(type_weight_id int,
constraint pk_types_weights primary key (type_id_weight),
type_id int,
weight_id int,
foreign key fk_types_weights_type foreign key type_id references types (type_id),
foreign key fk_types_weights_weigh foreign key weight_id references (weight_id),
creator_id int,
competition_id,
constraint fk_types_weights_creator foreign key (creator_id) references project_leaders(leader_id),
constraint fk_types_weights_competition foreign key (competition_id) references competitions(competition_id),
created_at datetime,
...
);
```

and now you need a table to join everything in the relational model

```
create table competition_participants
(competition_id int,
user_id int,
type_weight_id,
constraint pk_competition_participants primary key (competition_id, user_id, type_weight_id),
constraint fk_competition_participants_competition foreign key (competition_id) references competitions (competition_id),
constraint fk_competition_participants_users foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id),
constraint fk_competiton_participants_types_weights (type_weight_id) references types_weights (type_weight_id), 
created_at datetime,
...
);
```

---

And this should do the trick, now change the schema to met your specification...

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you so much. I do indeed already have users, team leaders and competitions - it was just the types/weightings that was a challenge, but I think you've cleared it up - for now anyway!

Comment: now don't forget to vote up the answer and flag it as the right answer :)

Comment: Of course :) Will make sure I come back with some progress for ya !